# `git config --global alias.past = log --pretty=format:"%h|%ad|%s" --date=local` doesn't work

Tags: git, cmd, alias

I want to create this alias so that `git past` is equivalent to `git log --pretty=format:"%h|%ad|%s" --date=local`. However, when I run the command `git config --global alias.past = log --pretty=format:"%h|%ad|%s" --date=local` in cmd, it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkiFJ.png), and then the `git past` command doesn't work.

What is going wrong? The git config manual suggests this format of creating aliases.
How do I get the desired alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two mistakes here. First, you need to drop the `=` character. Second, since the command you want to alias to contains whitespaces, you need to surround it with quotes:

```
git config --global alias.past "log --pretty=format:'%h|%ad|%s' --date=local"
```

Comment: What you are saying, exactly that I did first, because it's written in the book progit. But that didn't work and I performed the command `git help config` and found this syntax (which I've written in the question).

Comment: @Martund It seemed to work when I tested this. Can you elaborate on how this isn't working for you?

Comment: It's giving the same output, of which I added screenshot in the question.

Comment: @Martund That doesn't sound right. Are you sure you copy-pasted exactly what I wrote, including the quotes? Can you share a screenshot including the command you ran?

Comment: In `cmd` single quotes (apostrophes) don't work. Use double quotes: `git config --global alias.past "log --pretty=format:%h|%ad|%s --date=local"`

Comment: @Martund I missed the fact that you were using `cmd`. As @phd pointed out, you should use double quotes, not single quotes - see my edited answer.

Comment: Even your edited answer doesn't work @Mureinik. The trick in phd's comment lies in the fact that there is no space in the format string, and therefore we can drop quotes there. The output of your answer is `'%ad' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @Mureinik Double quotes inside double quotes?!

Comment: @phd *facepalm* was not paying attention... Thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed.